# WebdriverIO Sync to Async - is it confined to a minimum Node version?

Tags: async-await, webdriver-io

I am working on upgrading our test library which uses WebdriverIO. I am refactoring our tests to support async calls. I have made all the changes based on Node v16.x.x and our tests are passing however...and this is where my question lies..should this still build if using Node version 14.x.x?

I have followed the guide on the WebdriverIO site but there is no mention of Node versioning.
I am seeing problems with npm install:

```
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I understand this is related to node module dependency installation.

This is what I am using:

```
"@wdio/cli": "^7.5.2",
"@wdio/jasmine-framework": "^7.4.6",
"@wdio/junit-reporter": "^7.4.2",
"@wdio/local-runner": "^7.5.1",
"@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.5.0",
"@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.5.2",

Node v14.20.0
NPM 6.14.17
```

And I have updated my tsconfig according to the suggestions on the WebdriverIO guide:

```
"target": "ES2018",
"types": [
      "node",
      "webdriverio/async",
      "@types/jest"
    ],
```

Can someone shine some light on what I might be doing wrong or is Node 14 not compatible?

I tried Node 14 with all the async/await calls and npm fails.

If I upgrade to Node 16 then I don't seem to have the problem but we have some consuming products that are still using Node 14.

Comment: Update: turns out the issue was totally unrelated to webdriverIO...my mistake...local repository and auth issues.